# How do I reset app cache and reload during runtime? iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an app that uploads/view images to a database. Users are able to edit the images and re-upload. I was getting this problem where the file on the server was actually changed but even though the app was making calls to download new copies of the file the image still displayed the old version even when exiting app and reloading. Users had to completely uninstall app and reinstall to see new images.

I use this function now to clear the app cache and everything so it can get redownloaded from the database.

```
NSString *p = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
for (NSString *fname in @[ @"tmp", @"Library", @"Documents", @"Caches",   @"Preferences" ]) {
    NSString *path = [p stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
}
```

Now when I close the app and do a clean start the proper images are displayed. Unfortunately i cannot get the new images to display during app runtime even after calling this function. I must exit and do a clean start of the app.

Is there any way to reset the cache and reload the app cleanly so I stay on my current app state during runtime but get the effect i desire.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete files in your bundle. The bundle is not writable.

Instead, use the application documents directory to store your images. Maybe you first want to copy some images from the bundle to the documents directory on first run.